# Formatting dashes in string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-formatting, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I have just been checking out the new string interpolation feature in C# 6.0 (refer to the [Language Features page at Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20feature%20status&referringTitle=Home) for further detail). With the current syntax (which is expected to change), you can do something like this (example taken from a blog post I'm writing just now):

```
var dob2 = "Customer \{customer.IdNo} was born on \{customer.DateOfBirth:yyyyMdd}";
```

However, I can't seem to include dashes in the formatting part, such as:

```
var dob2 = "Customer \{customer.IdNo} was born on \{customer.DateOfBirth:yyyy-M-dd}";
```

If I do that, I get the error:

> Error CS1056  Unexpected character '-'    StringInterpolation Program.cs  21

Is there any way I can get dashes to work in the formatting part? I know I can just use string.Format(), but I want to see if it can be done with string interpolation, just as an exercise.

**Edit**: since it seems like nobody knows what I'm talking about, see [my blog post](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/c-6-preview-string-interpolation/) on the subject to see how it's supposed to work.

Comment: How is this question unclear? It says exactly what's needed to reproduce the error and what is the expected behavior.

Comment: The problem likely has absolutely nothing to do with string interpolation, and everything to do with calling `customer.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-M-dd");`.  Check if you can call the `ToString` method with the format string, outside of all the unnecessary interpolation stuff.

Comment: @abelenky It's a compile time error, not an exception.

Comment: Just a guess here - perhaps you can nest the interpolations to format the date?

Comment: Then it seems likely you have found a bug in the parser.  It is treating `-` as a Negation / Minus-sign, instead of as part of a literal format-string, and it believes that subtraction is not appropriate at this point in the code.  In fact, it looks like you already know this in your blog: *"as it seems the compiler treats them as an operator."*  So you came here to complain about a bug on a preview version of unfinished software?   I don't see how we can "answer" that "question".

Comment: @abelenky it's not necessarily a bug - if you can use expressions in string interpolation (which I haven't tried just yet), then the minus sign would be perfectly legit. I'm not complaining about anything - I just want to see if it's possible to include format strings with dashes in this feature.

Comment: Have you attempted: `"... \{customer.DateOfBirth:\"yyyy-M-dd\"}";`?

Comment: Would you please consider updating the answer to @Mike Trusov given that C#6 is fully released now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the version of string interpolation that's in VS 2015 Preview, you can use characters like dashes in the interpolation format by enclosing it in another pair of quotes:

```
var dob2 = "Customer \{customer.IdNo} was born on \{customer.DateOfBirth : "yyyy-M-dd"}";
```

Answer (score 60):

The final version is more user friendly:

```
var text = $"The time is {DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}";
```